# How Do i Find The Top Ten Newest Objects in the Mongoose Array | Discord.js MongooseDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongoose

Hey So I Want to Make it List only the 10 Newest Objects in a Mongoose Array, Currently it Lists it all

My Current Code:

```
ProofModel.findOne({ id: guildId }, async (err, data) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    if(data.Proofs.length) {
        embed.setDescription(
            data.Proofs.map(
                (w, i) => 
                `\`${i + 1}\` | User : ${message.guild.members.cache.get(w.user).user.tag} | Proof : [Click Here To Veiw](${w.proof})`
            )
        )

        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
});
```

Schema:

[image: Schema]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the $slice operator. Docs are [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/).

The code you are looking for is something like this:

```js
ProofModel.findOne({ id: guildId } , { Proofs: { $slice : -10 } } , async (err, data) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    if(data.Proofs.length) {
        embed.setDescription(
            data.Proofs.map(
                (w, i) => 
                `\`${i + 1}\` | User : ${message.guild.members.cache.get(w.user).user.tag} | Proof : [Click Here To Veiw](${w.proof})`
            )
        )

        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to slice off a select portion of an array. To assist with your problem, you can use **negative** numbers as arguments so you can cut out elements from the back. Here's a demo:

```js
// sample arr that scaled from 1-100
// [1, 2, 3, ..., 98, 99, 100]
const arr = Array.from({ length: 100 }, (v, i) => i + 1);

// slice off the last ten elements
// for use separately
console.log(arr.slice(-10));
```